# Looking for files for printed parts for my Kossel XL kit from Builda3Dprinter.eu

Tags: printer-building, delta, kossel

A couple years back I received a Kossel XL kit from builda3dprinter.eu as a gift, but I stopped building it because multiple parts were missing, including printed parts. Now that I'm building a Prusa MK3S, I'm considering buying some of the parts and finding the stl files to print the printed parts. However I'm having a bit of trouble finding the files for the exact model, and finding the printed parts for the XL, rather than the mini. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and advice from people who built the same printer would be incredible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bought 2 of these kits 4 years ago, and I have been really pleased with the quality of the kits and the results.  Sadly this supplier is no longer trading, as he could not compete with low cost imports from the far east.

I have the STL files for the printer kit, so you should be able to print any parts you need.

I have created a [Github repository with a ZIP file of the parts files](https://github.com/jsryork/Kossel-XL-printable-parts) I downloaded from the builda3dprinter.eu website.